# Trigger Print of ReportViewer VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms, reportviewer

I am using VB.net and Winforms reportviewer for showing the reports generated using SQL Server Reporting Service.
I want to trigger the print of the reportviewer from code behind. Please help me in doing the same.

```
 Dim usern = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString()
        rptViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote
        rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri("http://myserver/Reportserver")
        rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Management Reports/InvoicReport"
        Dim parm As ReportParameter
        parm = New ReportParameter("parInvoiceID", InvoiceID)
        rptViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(parm)
        rptViewer.ServerReport.Refresh()
        Me.rptViewer.RefreshReport()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on RenderingComplete event of rptViewer write below code

```
rptViewer.PrintDialog()
```